# updating cells in gspread beyond 26

Tags: python, gspread

I am trying to automate the rostering system on google sheets for my work (I work in a book store and I am learning to code as a hobby).. I have created two lists, one with time slots, the other with days which I want to print across the spreadsheet.

Here is my code so far:

```html
days = ["Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday"]
daysIter = iter(days)
timeslots = ["8:00AM","8:30AM","9:00AM","9:30AM","10:00AM","10:30AM","11:00AM","11:30AM",
             "12:00PM","12:30PM","1:00PM","1:30PM","2:00PM","2:30PM","3:00PM","3:30PM","4:00PM","4:30PM",
             "5:00PM","5:30PM","6:00PM","6:30PM","7:00PM","7:30PM","8:00PM","8:30PM","9:00PM","9:30PM"]


timesIter = iter(timeslots)

daysonsheet = sheet.range("A2:A7")
timesonsheet = sheet.range("C1:AD1")

    


sheet.update_acell('A1',days[0])
for cell in daysonsheet:
    cell.value = next(daysIter)
    sheet.update_cells(daysonsheet)

sheet.update_acell('B1',timeslots[0])
for cell1 in timeslots:
    cell1.value = next(timesIter)
    sheet.update_cells(timesonsheet)
```

I am able to update daysonsheet fine, but timesonsheet throws:

```html
  File "/Users/*******/Rostering2", line 52, in <module>
    cell1.value = next(timesIter)

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'value'
```

As far as I can tell they are both the same, but 'cell' in the for loop that works is not created as an object and 'cell1' is for some reason..

If anyone could shed some light on this, that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

The `timeslots` in your code is a list of strings, which does not have the `.value` attribute. You should be looping through a list of `Cell` objects, which is `timeonsheet`. Also, consider moving the `sheet.update_cells` call outside of the loop to save on API calls.

```
for cell1 in timesonsheet:
    cell1.value = next(timesIter)
sheet.update_cells(timesonsheet)
```

Comment: also apologies for the incorrect title, this was a previous issue and forgot to switch the title